# Windows Number Pad Not Working

Tags: mac, keyboard

I have a Dell keyboard with a built-in number pad. On some applications when I use it, it works normally. On IntelliJ, when I type on the number pad, it doesn't type at all. On Excel, it primarily types with spaces between the numbers/symbols. How could I fix this or do I need to get an Apple keyboard?

I have a Mac mini (Late 2014) running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: Please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/334249/edit) the question to include the type of Mac you are using with the version of macOS.

Comment: The number pad keys are sending the same scan codes as the numbers across the top.  If they are working in "some" applications and not others, there's an issue with those apps specifically.  Can you expand on what happens in Excel?  Are you saying it adds a space after each number press?

Comment: @Allan Most of the time it adds a space after each number, but sometimes it doesn't add a space after the number.

Comment: *When* does it exhibit this behavior?  What apps?  Can you take a screen capture using QuickTime?

Comment: On Excel, it looks like [this](https://dssecret.github.io/screenShot.png).

Comment: A regular Mac extended keyboard does not send the same codes for the 'qwerty' vs 10-key. Test with [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (App Store, freeware)

Comment: On IntelliJ, when I type into the Terminal with the number pad, it just goes to the code and enters the numbers there.

Comment: For comparison, 1 on 'qwerty' is key code 18, 1 on 10-key is 83. [UK International extended keyboard]